# rush is installed on every commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, rush

We have a git pre-commit hook set up that runs prettier through rush, following the instructions [here](https://rushjs.io/pages/maintainer/enabling_prettier/#enabling-the-git-hook)

```
node common/scripts/install-run-rush.js prettier || exit $?
```

Every time I commit, I get a new install of rush. My guess is that there's something wrong in my env that's keeping this script from recognizing that rush is already installed, but I can't figure out what based on inspecting the script.

What could I change or investigate?